# Stubborn bit won't be set to one.

Tags: c, binary, ieee-754, ieee

I have this code I use for getting the mantissa, or value, of an IEEE binary number.

```
iFloat_t floatGetVal (iFloat_t x) {
  iFloat_t mantissa = (BITS == 16) ? (x & 0x03FF)
                      : (x & 0x007FFFFF);
    debug("%s: getVal before implicit 1", getBinary(mantissa));
    //mantissa = (BITS == 16) ? (mantissa | 0x04)
    //                : (mantissa | 0x008);
    mantissa = x | 0000010000000000;
    debug("%s: getVal after implicit 1", getBinary(mantissa));
    mantissa = (BITS == 16) ? (mantissa & 0x07FF)
                      : (mantissa & 0x00FFFFFF);
    if(floatGetSign(x) == 1) {
        mantissa = ~mantissa + 1;
    }
    return mantissa;
}
```

My issue is when I try to get the value from the number 63.125, here is the corresponding output:

```
DEBUG iFloat.c[31] floatGetVal() 0000-0011-1110-0100: getVal before implicit 1
DEBUG iFloat.c[35] floatGetVal() 0101-0011-1110-0100: getVal after implicit 1
DEBUG iFloat.c[81] floatAdd() 0000-0011-1110-0100: bits of val_y after assignment
```

This is my expected output:

```
DEBUG iFloat.c[31] floatGetVal() 0000-0011-1110-0100: getVal before implicit 1
DEBUG iFloat.c[35] floatGetVal() 0101-0111-1110-0100: getVal after implicit 1
DEBUG iFloat.c[81] floatAdd() 0000-0111-1110-0100: bits of val_y after assignment
```

Here is my full code:

https://pastebin.com/w4UVzmUe

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`0000010000000000` is an octal literal, not a binary one, use hexadecimal `0x0400`.

Answer (score 1):

There are no binary constants in standard C. So you cannot have something like `0b0000010000000000`. But GCC has an [extension](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Binary-constants.html) to support them with `0b` or `0B` prefixes.

If you are not using GCC, then better go with the suggestion provided by @zch.